# Recode columns using data with variable names in rows

Tags: r, plyr

I have two data frames:

- Lookup table `lookup` with columns `varName` (variable name), `key`, and `value`
- Data frame `df` with columns named exactly as values in `varName` and values corresponding to `key` (values in `df` are keys to `lookup`). This data frame is much bigger than lookup data frame (e.g. 1e6 rows).

I would like to recode data in `df` by appending new column for every variable, where key in `df` is replaced by corresponding `value` from `lookup` data frame. It is important to note that keys are of type double.

Sample data:

```
# Generate sample data
lookup <- data.frame(
  varName = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3),
  key     = runif(9),
  value   = runif(9)
  )

df <- expand.grid(
  A = lookup[lookup$varName == 'A', 'key'],
  B = lookup[lookup$varName == 'B', 'key'],
  C = lookup[lookup$varName == 'C', 'key']
  )
```

My current solution uses temporary renaming of variables and `join` from `plyr`:

```
require(plyr)

for (varName in unique(lookup$varName)) {
  tmpLookup <- rename(lookup, replace = c(key = varName))
  df[paste0(varName, '_value')] <- join(df[varName], tmpLookup[c(varName, 'value')], 
                                        by = varName)['value']  
}

df
```

Questions:

- is this safe? I cannot find any information if joining `double` will work always correctly using `join`
- is there better way to accomplish the same safer and faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `data.table`.  Using a `set.seed(20)` for creating the "df" (for reproducibility).  Instead of the "wide" format, I am reshaping "df" to "long" using `melt`, converted to "data.table" (`as.data.table`), set the key columns (`setkey(..)`), join the "lookup" dataset, convert it back to "wide" format with `dcast.data.table`, and finally join the original dataset so as to have to new and old columns in the dataset.  This could be also done using a `for` loop without `reshaping`

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
DT <- as.data.table(melt(as.matrix(df)))
DT1 <- dcast.data.table(setkey(DT, Var2,
           value)[lookup], Var1~Var2, value.var='i.value')
DT2 <- setkey(setDT(df)[,Var1:=1:.N], Var1)[DT1][,Var1:=NULL]

head(DT2,2)
#          A         B          C       i.A         i.B       i.C
#1: 0.8775214 0.5291637 0.09133259 0.3700745 0.001927939 0.4520996
#2: 0.7685332 0.5291637 0.09133259 0.7155276 0.001927939 0.4520996
```

Comment: The second line (`DT1`) fails with error: `Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : some columns are not in the data.table: Var2`.

Comment: @TomasGreif I am not able to reproduce the error using `data.table_1.9.5`